# Start WSGI script at apache startup

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I have flask script running through WSGI on an apache server.
After a server reboot, the apache server is started but the python script is only started at the first request. Is there a way to make it start as soon as the server starts so it runs all the time?

What is the default of the `inactivity-timeout` setting? Can I prevent the server from stopping the script if there are no imcoming requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's the idea of scripting, it runs when somebody, or somethings requires it. Read more about [lazy loading](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

You may use `cron` and `curl` to make some fake requests. You may also execute the `curl` by editing the `init` script or ...

The default for `inactivity-timeout` is 2.0s ([reference](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives)). Max should be `sss` which is `999s` (~`16 min`).

Your issue may be related though to caching.

**Update**: [WSGIImportScript](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIImportScript) directive can be used to specify a script file to be loaded when a process starts - thanks @sean-vieira

Comment: Also worth noting for the OP that `WSGIImportScript` may help him: "For some cases, such as when WSGIScriptAlias is being used, it is actually possible to preload the application code when the processes first starts, rather than when the first request arrives. To preload an application see the [WSGIImportScript](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIImportScript) directive."

Comment: The default inactivity-timeout is not 2.0 seconds. That annotation means that that option is only available with mod_wsgi 2.0 or later. By default inactivity timeouts are off.